# SAS Find average values over several datasets

Tags: sas, average

I have several datasets each with the same structure and I would like to find the average of the values in each cell of the table.

eg. Say I have three tables each with 3 rows (A-C) and 2 columns (1-2), how can I calculate the average values of these cells ?

```
  1 2    1 2    1 2
A 2 1  A 0 1  A 4 1
B 9 0  B 0 2  B 0 1
C 1 5  C 2 2  C 3 2
```

The result would thus be:

```
  1 2
A 2 1
B 3 1
C 2 3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concatenate the datasets together, then use a PROC (e.g. MEANS or SUMMARY) to calculate the average..

Assuming your tables are called `table1`, `table2`, `table3`, and the `A` to `C` values are in a variable called `GROUP` and the numeric values are `VAL1` and `VAL2` :

```
data master ;
  set table1-table3 ;
run ;

proc summary data=master nway ;
  class GROUP ;
  var VAL1 VAL2 ;
  output out=averages (drop=_:) mean= ;
run ;

proc print ; run ;
```

If the source datasets are large in size, consider creating `master` as a view instead of a dataset :

```
data master / view=master ;
  set table1-table3 ;
run ;

...
```